# Calculate percentile in Vertica database

Tags: sql, vertica

I've been trying, in vain, to return rows from a specific percentile but I keep getting wrong values. The values of `SCORE` in the database is where the percentile should be calculated from.

This is my query. I'm trying to get all values that are in the top 10%.

```
select x.count, MBR_NAME, MBR_ID, SCORE,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SCORE) OVER (PARTITION BY x.count) AS PERCENTILE
from tbSCORES_INFO, (select count(*) as count FROM tbSCORES_INFO) as x
```

When I run this query, I get a fixed value as percentile and it's the same for all rows.

The desired output should be to return all rows that falls in the `xth` percentile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `ntile()`:

```
select i.*, ntile(10) over (order by x.score) as decile
from tblscores_info i;
```

If you want the top 10%, then use a subquery:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*, ntile(10) over (order by x.score) as decile
      from tblscores_info i
     ) i
where decile = 10;
```

The `PERCENTILE()` functions return the *value* that is the breaking point.  `NTILE()` actually assigns the "percentile".

Comment: Works like a charm! I never came across ntile before